# joining row with most recent date in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm new to mysql and have been tryn to make this work without any luck.
i am joining 3 tables and i am tryn to join third table with the row with most recent record as per date.
here is my mysql query

```
SELECT mg.region_name, mu.contact_person, 
    mu.contact_number, mu.status, mu.company_name, mu.user_type, MAX(mf.follow_up_date), mf.date, mu.user_id
FROM p1006_marketing_group as mg 
JOIN p1006_marketing_users as mu ON mg.id = mu.region_id 
JOIN ( SELECT user_id_fk,MAX(follow_up_date) 
        FROM p1006_marketing_follow_up ) as mf 
    ON mu.user_id = mf.user_id_fk 
    WHERE mu.user_id_done = "" AND ( mg.id = 3 OR mg.id = 7 OR mg.id = 6 ) 
GROUP BY mf.user_id_fk
```

i get the following error

Unknown column 'mf.follow_up_date' in 'field list'

i am really confused because i do have to column follow_up_date.

i would be really greateful for any help possible

Comment: Your 2nd join will return only one row unless you use a group by user id

Comment: Your query is rife wtih errors.  Please edit your question and, first, give 2-3 sentences about what the query is supposed to be doing.  If you have more time than this, then add some sample and expected output.  I see so many problems that I can't even formulate an answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , i'll do that asap.. thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten to give your MAX(follow_up_date) inside your subquery, an alias

Edit your query so it looks like:

```
MAX(follow_up_date) as follow_up_date
```

Please also note, your query has other issues, such as the select list containing about 8 columns that are not part of an aggregate function, but your group by lists only one column. While this might work in MySQL because it can (if configured so) fill in missing group by columns for you, you should really get into the habit of specifying them, to avoid future issues in other employment that uses different database systems

Comment: thanks for the help, it took care of the error but now i am getting a null array for some reason . also thanks for taking out time and and mentioning the valuable suggestions . ia m really new to this so need all the help possible

Comment: If, by '!null array' you mean 'my query is not returning any results', remove the where clause and run it again, then start adding bits back in til it disappears.. then you'll find out why. If it still gives no results even without a where clause, there is a problem with one or more of your joins (there are no matching records for the join)

Comment: i will try that .. thanks a lot for your time and effort

Answer (score 1):

You are missing alias for MAX column.

```
SELECT 
  mg.region_name, mu.contact_person, mu.contact_number, mu.status, 
  mu.company_name, mu.user_type, MAX(mf.follow_up_date), mf.date, mu.user_id

FROM p1006_marketing_group as mg 
JOIN p1006_marketing_users as mu ON mg.id = mu.region_id 
JOIN ( SELECT user_id_fk,MAX(follow_up_date) 'follow_up_date' FROM p1006_marketing_follow_up ) as mf ON mu.user_id = mf.user_id_fk 
WHERE mu.user_id_done = "" AND ( mg.id = 3 OR mg.id = 7 OR mg.id = 6 ) 
GROUP BY mf.user_id_fk
```

Comment: Is there an echo in here? :)

Comment: thanks for the help, it took care of the error but i am still getting a null array for some reason .:(